# How to use custom cursor in window non-client area using Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, cursor, delphi-xe4

I have custom Delphi VCL control that intercepts `WM_NCHITTEST` message and returns `HTCAPTION` to make control movable on its parent window.

That part works fine, but returning `HTCAPTION` also resets my custom cursor to Windows default one when hovering over that control. Is there any way I can use `HTCAPTION` and still show my custom cursor?

**Note:** I know how to implement control movement without using `HTCAPTION` and solve cursor issue that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `WM_SETCURSOR` message handler:

```
procedure TCustomVCLControl.WMSetCursor(var Message: TWMSetCursor);
begin
  SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[cr..]);
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to do `if Message.HitTest <> HTCAPTION then SetCursor(...);` ?

Comment: @TLama - What I understand from the question is that the hit test is always HTCAPTION. If it's not, of course.

Comment: @TLama hit test is always `HTCAPTION`, so additional test is not necessary, but otherwise you are correct.

Comment: @Dalija, even when you're just hovering the control, e.g. ? If so, then I don't understand that parameter at all.

Comment: @TLama - Hit testing is not related with clicks, it's identified just by position. The result effects what a click will cause though. It's a bit mis-named maybe..

Comment: @Sertac, I see, but I still not follow. My initial point was simple; do not call `SetCursor` (do not change the mouse cursor) if `Message.HitTest` value equals to `HTCAPTION` (which is the one when the cursor is unintentionally changed). Or maybe just *eat* the message if the hit test is `HTCAPTION`, otherwise let the VCL do the rest. In other words, prevent that change when hit test is `HTCAPTION`.

Comment: @TLama - If you don't change the cursor, the default window procedure will set it to the default cursor (arrow). The question asks how to use a different cursor. You can't eat WM_NCHITTEST or WM_SETCURSOR, they are not posted to the queue. Besides, that would probably prevent a button press to generate a mouse down message.

Comment: @TLama - Maybe the confusion is about what the VCL does about the cursor. Nothing if the hit test is not `HTCLIENT`. For this control it is always `HTCAPTION`. (Nothing means, VCL does not call `SetCursor`, instead the default window procedure calls it with the default cursor.)